# Function related to perfect squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For each positive integer $n$, let $f(n)$ be the smallest integer $r$ for which there is an increasing
sequence of integers $n = a_1 < a_2 < · · · < a_k = r$ such that the product $a_1a_2 · · · a_k$ is a
perfect square. For example, $f(2) = 6, f(3) = 8, f(4) = 4, f(8) = 15$. Prove that $f$ is a
one­ to­ one function.

Here is my attempt:

Clearly, if $f(a) = b = c$, then $b =c$.

To show that if $f(a) = f(b)$ then $a=b$, I tried to let

$f(n) = f(n+a) = n+a+b$ for some $a,b,n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then,

$n(n+p_1)(n+p_2)...(n+p_k)(n+a+b)$ and $(n+a)(n+a+q_1)...(n+a+q_l)(n+a+b)$ are perfect squares for some sets A = $\{p_1, p_2,...,p_k\}$ and B= $\{q_1, q_2,...,q_l\}$ with

A $\subset \{1,2,...a+b-1\}$ and B $\subset \{1,2,...b-1\}$.

I don't have any clue how to proceed from here, any hints or solutions are appreciated

Comment: Related: https://oeis.org/A006255

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose we had two good sequences ending at the same natural number:

$$(a_1,a_2, \cdots, a_n)\quad \&\quad (b_1,b_2,\cdots, b_m)$$ with $a_n=b_m=N$ and $a_1\neq b_1$.

Of course this implies that $f(a_1)=f(b_1)=N$.

Without loss of generality, assume that $a_1<b_1$.

We note that $$\frac {\prod a_i\times \prod b_j}{N^2}$$ is a perfect square.

Continuing in this manner, we can eliminate every natural number which is common to both sequences.

We are then left with two disjoint sequences $$(A_1,\cdots, A_k)\quad \& \quad (B_1,\cdots, B_l)$$  such that the product $\prod A_i\times \prod B_j$ is a perfect square and the maximal element is less than $N$.

Noting that $a_1=A_1$ is the least term in the sequence, this means that $f(a_1)≤\max (\{A_i\}\cup \{B_j\})<N$ contradicting the definition of $N$, and we are done.